# I cannot figure out this while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am having a little trouble with the code below, basically I am just practicing with loops and thought about making a little game to brush up...however I am a little stumped as to why the while loop is letting through an entry like "cat" or "hgh" for example, therefore making the alert at the end to say a load of gibberish....

```
    var playerWeapon = prompt("Before you go to slay the Dragon, please choose your weapon from the following... \n\n1.) Sword \n2.) Crossbow\n3.) Dagger").toLowerCase();

    while( (playerWeapon == '' ) && (playerWeapon != 'sword' || playerWeapon != 'dagger' || playerWeapon != 'crossbow') ){

       alert("We need you to pick a weapon...");

       var playerWeapon = prompt("Sorry, you need to chose a valid weapon...what will it be? \n\n1.) Sword \n2.) Crossbow\n3.) Dagger").toLowerCase();
                }

    var weaponStrength = '';

    if(playerWeapon == "sword"){
        var weaponStrength = 10;
    }
    if(playerWeapon == "dagger"){
        var weaponStrength = 7;
    }
    if(playerWeapon == "crossbow"){
        var weaponStrength = 4;
    }

    alert("Excellent, the " + playerWeapon + " is a fine choice and your weapon is " + weaponStrength + " strong...now lets go!");
```

Comment: Learn about `else if`

Comment: why is your prompt allowing them to select cat anyway?

Comment: @musefan Do you know what a prompt is? You can type anything!

Comment: @epascarello: Oh yeah... "that" prompt. I was thinking it was a custom thing for a second... of course that wouldn't have held up the execution now I think more about it... oh well, too late to worry now, I've already been spanked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `||` OR operator.

Given this code:

```
(playerWeapon != 'sword' || playerWeapon != 'dagger' || playerWeapon != 'crossbow')
```

Any word *(like "cat")* will clearly not be one of those three. You should use `&&` instead.

I'm not sure what the `== ""` test was intended to do, but if the requirement is one of those three weapons, then you don't need to test for an empty string.

Comment: @downvoter: If I missed something, please let me know.

Comment: If the weapon is dagger it's obviously not sword or crossbow ergo this statement will always return true.

Comment: @Dharman: Exactly. That's why `&&` is needed.

Comment: @Dharman - read the whole answer

Comment: Thanks chaps, got it now....i've not wrote any javascript for a year or so and just coming back into it...I'm still very rusty but all this is helping and making sense...Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Alex, glad you've fixed it. Just a point of style: it's best not to assume that everyone is male here, so "chaps" is probably inappropriate. I'd generalise that to the whole of Stack Overflow - have a read of [this meta article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176181/any-thoughts-on-how-to-react-to-gender-specific-language) when you get a moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`while ((playerweapon == '') && (the rest of the line means nothing because playerweapon has no value))`

your first test is playerweapon == '' (nothing) and then you test that it's not equal to some other values.  No point in that, if it's blank, it's blank

The line should be

`while(playerWeapon != 'sword' && playerWeapon != 'dagger' && playerWeapon != 'crossbow') {`

Comment: Also the second var is unnecessary. If variable is declared once doesn't need to be declared again.

Comment: @Dharman - your comment serves no purpose here

Comment: Easy does it Kevin. @Dharman's comment may have been somewhat better under the question, but nevertheless they are quite right. Let's make everyone welcome here.

Comment: @halfer - the point being that commenting on my answer doesn't necessarily help the OP (nor does it add to or detract from my answer) whereas commenting on the question is sure to be seen.

Comment: Agreed; it was just the (perceived) tone. Thanks Kevin `:)`.

Comment: Sorry, my responses are always terse and so my tone can be seen as abrupt :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your while condition:

```
(playerWeapon == '')
```

When `playerWeapon = 'cat'` that evaluates to `false` and `false && (...)` is always `false` so it breaks the loop. You need to swap your use of &&s and ||s to make that condition work. Try evaluating it by hand on paper and it should be obvious why.